# How to link a sheet from a different Excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In a Microsoft Excel file, I can *move or copy* a sheet from a different Excel file into this file.

[image]

Is it possible however to have the new sheet be a *reference* to the sheet in the other file? I would like to have a master file as an aggregate of sheets from secondary files.

In particular, whenever changes happen in those sheets in their owner files, the changes will reflect in the master spreadsheet.

Comment: You could have a formula in each cell that pulls from the respective cell of the reference sheet, but I don’t think referencing a whole sheet is possible.

Comment: If you only need reference cells from another Worksheet, you can use =A1...directly. If you want to fill or create tables based on the copied Worksheet, provide the sample here.